# How to set up WebDev.WebServer on Win 11 without installing MS Visual Studio?

Tags: webserver

I want to run aspx web site on local computer on Windows 11 Home edition without need to install MS Visual Studio which automatically install develepment server.

For that I need to register WebDev.WebHost40.dll and WebDev.WebHost20.dll in the assemblly and I can't do it Windows report error

I try to register WebDev.WebHost40.dll without success.